# Reconstructing Unity APK

Tags: debugging, apk

Note: I am only doing this for educational purposes with no intent to redistribute

I have decompiled an APK built with Unity successfully (Somewhat).
Using an array of programs, I managed to extract all the games assets and the scripts, though I am trying to re-construct it in unity to debug. I imported all the original scenes, and how they were set up (including all the attached scripts required) though I am receiving anywhere from 200-999+ errors in the console before I even run.

Some of these issues are from invalid characters (Decompiler-Generated fields) within scripts, which can easily be resolved by renaming them to a friendlier format, however, I sat here for a good hour resolving these errors, when I completed the last shown error, i hit play, and it generated another few hundred errors.

Why would it be that, if I was able to extract the scripts successfully (seemingly zero obfuscation), that, when imported into unity, I am thrown so many errors? Why is this not a 1:1 translatable process? Or is this problem based upon too many variables to be determined based off my question?

Programs used:

- dnSPY
- UtinyRipper

Comment: You can use a Tool specifically designed for Reverse Engineering Unity built APKs (and a few other Platforms) named "DevX".
You can find further detail on their website:
https://devxdevelopment.com/ P.S: I don't work at DevX nor associated with them in any way.

Answer (score 2):

Reconstructing a Unity project from binaries is often not possible because/when:

- the project was reconstructed in different version of Unity
- the reconstructed project uses different backend
- there were postprocesses applied that changed assets and scripts in a way that is not compatible with Unity
- bigger Unity projects sometimes use customized version of Editor or the engine

Also the reversing tools are not bug free.